# What does const {something} = Plugins mean in angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am building an ionic app and watched a tutorial youtube.com/watch?v=bww4a4B43tM to include notifications. Here he uses a code, which goes like

```
import {Plugins, LocalNotificationEnabledResult,LocalNotificationActionPerformed,LocalNotification,Device} from '@capacitor/core';
const {LocalNotifications} = Plugins;
```

However, I have trouble understanding what does the second line, `const {LocalNotifications} = Plugins;`, mean here?

I have seen such type of syntax in some angular applications as well, so I don't think it has to do something with ionic or capacitor.

Comment: This is not Angular specific, it is pure JavaScript, which is why it also exists in TypeScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: This *might* help: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#object-destructuring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is JavaScript [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax, used in your example for  extracting values nested within TypeScript `namespace` as  demonstrated below:

```js
// foo.ts
export namespace Namespace {
  export class Class {
    public name: string;
  }
  export function Function() {

  }
  export const value = 'some value...'
}

// app.ts
import { Namespace } from 'foo.ts';
const { Class, Function, value } = Namespace;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a general JS/TS thing, not specific to angular. It is called [Object Destructuring](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring), where you extract the specific properties of an object.